# Navigating to URL from Visualforce page in Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, app-development

I have a Custom link on my Order detail page that loads a VF page. When the VF page is completed, I want to take the user back to a refreshed Order detail view page. This is not working for me. What does work is if I do the same thing, but as an object-specific action on an account. I can then call the JS sfdc functions to refresh my detail page upon completion of the VF page. To illustrate the problem, the page below works when linked to an Account object-specific action but fails when linked to a Custom link off the Order detail page. Only difference is of course you need the change the StandardController to either Order or Account.

```
<apex:page standardController="Order" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" >
<script src='/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js'></script>
<body>
<div>
     <button id="doneButton">Done</button>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("doneButton").onclick = function(){
        console.debug(sfdc.publisher); // reports sfdc is undefined when used from Order VF page but works when used from Account VF page
        Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name: "publisher.close", payload: {refresh:"true"}});
    };
</script>
```

Note that I'd love to turn the Orders Custom link into an object-specific action but unfortunately that is not supported for orders, nor are Custom buttons for orders in Salesforce1. For some reason, the order object is rather locked down.

The custom link does work, in that I can bring up the VF page OK and get the info I need but I have not been able to find a way to navigate the user back to the refreshed order view detail page (other than telling them to hit the back arrow and that won't refresh the page). Doing it within Apex via a page reference results in the browser-based Salesforce detail page appearing. I don't seem to have access to the sfdc library and trying out navigation using sforce.one had no more success (sforce is undefined when I call it from the Order VF page).

I want to send the user back to a refreshed order detail view page in Salesforce1. Any tips on how to do so?